# Python: sort list of nested lists according to two criteria

Tags: python, list, sorting

In Python, I have a nested list like the following:

```
[ [[x1,y1,z1], [['0.9', 4], [0.8, 3], [0.5, 10], [0.1, 11]], 
  [[x2,y2,z2], [['1.0', 8], [0.8, 3], [0.2, 1], [0.1, 8]]
...]
```

So each element is in the form:

```
 [[3-tuple], [[val1, occurrences_of_val1], [val2, occurrences_of_val2],...]]
```

The second nested list is already sorted by the first item (val1 > val2 > val3 ...), but I want also the 3-tuples [x,y,z] to appear sorted in descending order according to two criteria:

1. value of val1 (highest first)
2. in case of same val1, highest occurrences_of_val1
   (possibly applied to val2 if the two values above are the same)

How do I do this? Probably with itemgetter, but I'm not sure in this case.

Comment: Could you clarify the link between `(x,y,z)` and [[val_1, nb_1],[val_2,nb_2],...]]` ?

Comment: `yourList.sort(key=lambda x: x[1][0], reverse=True)`

Comment: `yourList.sort(key=lambda x: x[1][0][0]), reverse=True)` but that applies only for val1. In case of more items with that value, I need to occurrences_of_val1 to count as well when sorting.

Comment: I edited the question a bit. In any case, [x,y,z] are the parameters I used on different samples, and what follows is a list of [output, occurrences_of_that_output]

Comment: @RickyRobinson:  `x[1][0]` gives you both items `[val1, occurrences_of_val1]`, which will sort the way you requested.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski -- Except it doesn't jump to `occurances_of_val2` if `val1` and `occurances_of_val1` are equal ...

Comment: @mgilson:  That was not originally specified, but this would do it: `yourList.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)`

Comment: Gotcha. Ideally, it should apply the same sorting for the remaining pairs in the second sublist: first `val_i`, then `occurrences_of_val_i`

Comment: @RickyRobinson -- I believe the solution by StevenRumbalski does that.

Comment: Fantastic. If `sort` handles all the fields in my list of lists, it's truly awesome.

Comment: @RickyRobinson: Then don't narrow down to `x[1][0]`, just leave the key as `x[1]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`yourList.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)`

Comment: I was just about to suggest you post this as an answer.

Comment: Do we know what's going on with the fact `val1` is a string but none of the others are?

Comment: @DSM: I noticed that.  It will cause issues if the values are not between `'0.0'` and `'9.9'`.  There is some datatype strangeness.  Also, I think the OP might be better off with a list of objects.

Comment: I just realised `val1` is indeed a string, but it seems that values (they are included in [0,1]) get sorted in the expected way.

Comment: It's ok then, `val_i` is in [0,1] for each `i`

Comment: @StevenRumbalski, are you sure it wouldn't be too much bother to create a list of objects?

Comment: Since '0.4' > 0.8, mixing strings and floats might not give the expected results, but I don't understand what's intended here.  @StevenRumbalski is right that the types involved are strange.

Comment: the logic was a life saver.. although it might not work correctly in the cases of overlapping when dealing with actually range but if we don't have that problem, it works like a charm

Answer (score 3):

I tested this

```
X=[ [[4,5,6], [[3.0, 4], [0.8, 3], [0.5, 10], [0.1, 11]]],
  [[2,1,3], [[2.0, 8], [0.8, 3], [0.2, 1], [0.1, 8]]]]
>>> X.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
>>> X
[[[2, 1, 3], [[2.0, 8], [0.80000000000000004, 3], [0.20000000000000001, 1], [0.10000000000000001, 8]]], [[4, 5, 6], [[3.0, 4], [0.80000000000000004, 3], [0.5, 10], [0.10000000000000001, 11]]]]
```

Most importantly, `X.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])` is sorting by second element of X, that is by this elements `[[val1, occurrences_of_val1], [val2, occurrences_of_val2],...]`. Implicitely, it is sorting by `val1`, then in case of equality by `occurrences_of_val1` ...

Comment: Can you explain how this line works: X.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])? It works but I don't quite understand it. Isn't it we need to pass in a function as an argument to the list.sort([fun])?